# Don't Understand SQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I've gone over this code several times but I cannot figure out why I'm getting

> Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'SR'

Here's my SELECT query:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.OrderID,OrderDetails.ProductCode,OrderDetails.Vendor_Price,OrderDetails.Quantity
FROM OrderDetails
JOIN
(SELECT OrderDetails.OrderID,  
CASE Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID WHEN  1 THEN 'S'  WHEN 2 THEN 'K' WHEN 3 THEN 'M' ELSE '' END 
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderDetails.OrderID)
AS 'SR'
WHERE OrderDetails.ShipDate IS NOT NULL
AND OrderDetails.ShipDate >= DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -6), 0)
ORDER BY OrderDetails.ProductCode ASC
```

It's pretty straightforward I just don't see the syntax error the computer is referring to.
Thanks.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'SR'`

Comment: @RUJordan I'm now getting incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'

Comment: Unquote the table alias - should be SR, not 'SR'. Add the missing 'ON' clause after it; it's `JOIN <table> ON <columnA> = <columnB>`, and you're missing the `ON` and columns to JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change 'SR' to SR. There is no need for quotes.

**[UPDATE]**

You also forget ON statement after AS SR

```
JOIN (select query...) as SR on SR.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
```

I guess it should be OrderID if not change it to whatever you need.

**[UPDATE 3] REPLACE THE WHOLE QUERY**

BTW, I think you wont achieve the result with this query, you need to use the following:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.OrderID
            ,OrderDetails.ProductCode
            ,OrderDetails.Vendor_Price
            ,OrderDetails.Quantity
            ,CASE Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID WHEN  1 THEN 'S'  WHEN 2 THEN 'K' WHEN 3 THEN 'M' ELSE '' END 
    FROM OrderDetails 
    JOIN #Also consider using INNER JOIN if needed
        Orders on Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId
    WHERE 
        OrderDetails.ShipDate IS NOT NULL
        AND OrderDetails.ShipDate >= DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -6), 0)
    ORDER BY OrderDetails.ProductCode ASC
```

Comment: you are missing the ON portion of your join, it should be above the where clause.

Comment: Sorry about that, yeah you forgot ON statement, updated answer

Comment: Thank you but now I'm getting `The multi-part identifier "OrderDetails.OrderID" could not be bound.`

Comment: @henryaaron Use the query I wrote for you in update3! Yours has too many issues.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have an `ON` statement after your `JOIN`

Comment: You got half the problem. :) I can't do half an upvote, though; SO won't let me.

Comment: I figured he could combine this answer with the others.

Comment: You should answer the entire question, or just comment on the other one providing the rest. As I said, I can't give half an upvote (and the poster can't split an acceptance).